# RadComboBox custom text needs to have Outlook behavior

Tags: javascript, telerik

We have a customized Telerik RadComboBox that builds a text string of names separated by semicolons in the textbox field of the combobox by selecting names from the dropdown.  We want to improve this and replicate a behavior similar to Outlook where individual names can be selected and deleted from the textbox.  The selected names are stored in a hidden input field.  Another hidden field carries a CSV list of IDs. Both hidden fields are treated like arrays, and their values have a one-to-one relationship by index.  The approach we are considering is to wrap some kind of tag around each name, like a span, so that when a user selects a particular name the whole name will be highlighted and can then somehow be detected.  Could this be done by using an ItemTemplate?

The OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event fires the javascript shown, and appends the list of names to the textbox.

```js
      function RecipientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
            var combo = $find('<%= rcbRecipients.ClientID%>');
            var userid = combo.get_selectedItem().get_value();
            var name = combo.get_selectedItem()._text;
            var listID = $get("<%= hdnRecipientIdList.ClientID%>").value;
            var listName = $get("<%= hdnRecipientNameList.ClientID%>").value;
            var listIDArray = new Array();
            var listNameArray = new Array();
            if (listID != '') {
                listIDArray = listID.split(',');
                listNameArray = listName.split('; ');
            }
            listNameArray.pop();
            for (var i = 0; i < listNameArray.length; i++) {
                listNameArray[i] = listNameArray[i] + '; ';
            }
            var x = listIDArray.indexOf(name);
            if (x == -1) {
                listIDArray.push(userid);
                listNameArray.push(name + '; ');
                listID = listIDArray.toString();
                var y = listNameArray.join('');
                listName = y;
            }
            $get("<%= hdnRecipientIdList.ClientID%>").value = listID;
            $get("<%= hdnRecipientNameList.ClientID%>").value = listName;

            combo.trackChanges();
            var item = combo.findItemByText(name);
            item.hide();

            combo.set_text(listName);
            combo.commitChanges();
            combo.showDropDown();
        }
```

Comment: I think Javascript is the only way to do a sutch advanced control.
But [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx) is perhaps a good an easy way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Looks like a good, intrinsic alternative that Telerik supports.

Comment: Btw Window Form have RadCheckedDropDownList  that are exactly but really exactly what you re looking for . I dont know why we don't have that. [Demo.gif](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/dropdown-listcontrol-and-checkeddropdownlist/checkeddropdownlist/how-to/images/dropdown-and-listcontrol-checkeddropdownlist-how-to001.gif)